# How do I set up vim to auto-complete like this?

Tags: vim

What I want is the following:

1. Pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> completes the current word I'm writing with the **longest common prefix, and nothing more**. I don't want to cycle through any options either, pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> again should return me to the original string preferably, or do nothing if that's not possible.
2. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> should pop up a menu showing all possible completions like the default vim.

Is this possible? I've found cycling through options / opening menus is extremely distracting for me while programming, and encourages the behaviour to keep cycling and hope that the completion I'm looking for is there.

Answer (score 2):

For the longest common text, use

```
:set completeopt+=longest
```

To avoid showing any other matches:

```
:set completeopt-=menu
```

`<C-N>` / `<C-P>` will still show the other matches; learn to use `<C-E>` to stop completion and go back to the originally typed text.

For the mapping:

```
function s:EnableCompleteMenu()
    set completeopt+=menu
    return ''
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <SID>EnableCompleteMenu s:EnableCompleteMenu()
inoremap <script> <C-Space> <SID>EnableCompleteMenu<C-N>
```

You could also use `<C-P>` for showing matches in the other direction. Note that the `<C-Space>` mapping probably only works in GVIM. If you want to use that together with the commands from above, you need to write a similar wrapper (with `:set completeopt-=menu`) and overload the other completion commands (`<C-N>`, etc.) with it.